# ERROR [08S01] Communication link failure while inserting data in to external table in netezza

Tags: netezza

I am trying to load data from text file to External table in **Netezza**.

Here is my command

```
INSERT INTO XTABLE_DHARMESH SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL 'C:\Dhams\mergeresult.txt' 
USING (delimiter ',' REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC' LOGDIR 'C:\Dhams');
```

I am getting `ERROR [08S01] Communication link failure.`

This error is occurring when I have 1 millions of records in file whereas it is working fine for 1000 records in my textfile.

Answer (score 3):

I have found in **Windows 7** and **Windows Server 2008 R2** TCP Chimney Settings were the culprit.

http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/sanderberkouwer/archive/2008/05/15/backward-compatible-networking-with-server-core.aspx

The Follwing Commands Fixed this issue for me:

```
netsh interface tcp set global rss=disabled
netsh interface tcp set global chimney=disabled
netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled
```

You can confirm that they were disabled with the following command

```
netsh int tcp show global
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this happens when using older firmware and ODBC drivers. It was fixed in Netezza firmware 7.0