# error of loading a data txt file to a table on Neteza

Tags: sql, database, netezza

I need to load a data txt file (a large file 32 GB) to a table in Neteza.

But, I got error:

```
 08S01 Communication link failure
 The communication link between the driver and the data source to which the driver was 
 attempting to connect failed before the SQLDriverConnect function completed processing.
```

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753042/error-08s01-communication-link-failure-while-inserting-data-in-to-external-tab) did not work for me. I am not allowed to change the TCP setting. I have no adm authorization.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to load your file with "NZLOAD" command with "-allowReplay" tag? if not than please try to use this command.

Hope this will help.